# What are the standard communication protocol been used for Mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios, spring, jakarta-ee, mobile

I want to know, what are the standard communication protocols that are used to transfer data between mobile apps and the J2EE or Spring based server side?

Comment: i think same as Java..

Comment: There is no standard but RESTful(JSON) is pretty common since lightweight and that's a good idea on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common way is to use a JSON over HTTP (RESTful). Spring has a pretty good REST implementation or you can use one of the [JSR311](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr311/) implementations like [Jersery](https://jersey.java.net/)

On the client/mobile side there are a lot of good frameworks to deal with REST, like [Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley) for Android and [RestKit](http://restkit.org/) for iOS.

Answer (score 1):

For most applications, HTTP(S) is the best protocol to use. The overhead (i.e. headers) is pretty small, the transfer can be gzipped, the connection can be secured (via SSL). Also, ports 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS) will be open in 99% of cases. Other ports are not -- for example some carriers block all other ports unless you pay extra.

As for the implementation, I suggest a RESTful web service using the JSON format. JSON is well standardized, has small overhead and you have good libraries for working with it in any language (check out org.json, which is bundled with Android but can be downloaded as standalone for other applications as well). Check out this question, too:

A better Java JSON library?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP(S) + JSON or XML + OAuth is the best set. In Java you can use google-gson library for JSON and oauth-signpost for OAuth.